# how can I fix "build failed" after I run react-native run-android in windows 10

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created the project very well and I have also installed the android studio and all the required sdks. but still I am still facing a problem of the emulator not starting. below is error in the terminal.

'$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier"
flag.
(node:8368) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 866 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 6 workers...
info Starting JS server...
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\jayde\Desktop\KYC\Zipcomply\android\local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\jayde\Desktop\KYC\Zipcomply\android\local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\jayde\Desktop\KYC\Zipcomply\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)        
at C:\Users\jayde\Desktop\KYC\Zipcomply\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\jayde\Desktop\KYC\Zipcomply\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\jayde\Desktop\KYC\Zipcomply\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANDROID_HOME` is Deprecated (in Android Studio), use `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` instead.

Configure the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable

1. Open the Windows Control Panel.
2. Click on User Accounts, then click
   User Accounts again
3. Click on Change my environment variables
4. Click on New... to create a new `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` user variable that points to the path to your Android SDK:

The SDK is installed, by default, at the following location:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk
```

You can find the actual location of the SDK in the Android Studio "Settings" dialog, under **Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK**.

Comment: thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1. Go to your React-native Project -> Android
2. Create a file local.properties
3. Paste

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

4. Replace USERNAME with your user name

Answer (score 0):

Check Your SDK path and you have installed correct sdk according to version.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ANDROID_HOME Variable name To ANDROID_SDK_ROOT or create one if it doesn't exist already.

1. Browse to C:/Users//AppData/Android/SDK
2. Copy the path from the explorer
3. Hit START and type "environment variables"
   [ScreenShot][1]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6b5G.png
4. Look for a button which says environment variables and click it
5. click "New" variable under either user variables or system variables.
6. paste "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" in the variable name field and
7. SAVE and Restart Your PC if needed.

-----------------------DONE------------------------